# The user gets "Unknown file type" when open docx with Word 2003

Tags: c#, ms-word, mime-types, content-type, word-2003

One of my customers has problems with opening of word documents. He gets "Unknown file type" when he downloads a .docx file. He has Word 2003 with plugin for .docx compatibility installed. He uses IE7 if it does matter.

The document is been sent by

```
return File(stream, "application/docx", fileName);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the file downloaded correctly? Can hthe client open other *.docx-files? May the downloaded file is damaged...

Comment: He can open others files with .docx extentions. Downloaded file is ok, if he adds .doc or .docx it is been opened correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try `application/msword`

[See here](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried. I get "Microsoft Word 97-2003 Document" even I have Word 2010 installed. It is not good for users who have Word 2010 to get old doc format. I have to test with the user also.